# Подключение к Базе Данных при помощи утилиты HeidiSQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных

У меня стоит локалка Open Server. Хочу подключиться к БД через утилиту HeidiSQL. Выдаёт ошибку "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'(using password:NO)". Как быть? Что делать? Не подскажите??[image: ошибка показана на фото]

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка означает, что отсутствуют права доступа для пользователя root.
Т.к. вы используете сервер OpenServer, для авторизации БД MySQL по умолчанию используется:

> Пользователь: root

> Пароль: root

Как видно из скриншота, вам необходимо задать пароль.